# SpringBoot 2.0.5 Application failing after start

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am upgrading my application from Spring 1.5.x to Spring 2.0.5. Whilst all the steps are completed and the required modules are also upgraded, the application starts successfully but then suddenly fails after 30-40 seconds. The strange part is, no error is reported. Just the following lines:

```
[INFO] AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext - Closing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@6b26e945: startup date [Wed Oct 31 12:23:59 GMT 2018]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@5f9d02cb
[INFO] DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Stopping beans in phase 2147483647
[INFO] DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Stopping beans in phase 2147483547
[INFO] DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Stopping beans in phase 0
[INFO] EventDrivenConsumer - Removing {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
[INFO] PublishSubscribeChannel - Channel 'filterprocessor-1.errorChannel' has 0 subscriber(s).
[INFO] EventDrivenConsumer - stopped _org.springframework.integration.errorLogger
[INFO] ThreadPoolTaskScheduler - Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
[INFO] IntegrationMBeanExporter - Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
[INFO] IntegrationMBeanExporter - Unregistering JMX-exposed beans
[INFO] IntegrationMBeanExporter - Summary on shutdown: errorChannel
[INFO] IntegrationMBeanExporter - Summary on shutdown: nullChannel
[INFO] IntegrationMBeanExporter - Summary on shutdown: _org.springframework.integration.errorLogger.handler
[INFO] AnnotationMBeanExporter - Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
[INFO] AnnotationMBeanExporter - Unregistering JMX-exposed beans
[INFO] ThreadPoolTaskExecutor - Shutting down ExecutorService 'appShellThreadPoolTaskExecutor'
```

It seems AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext is introduced in Spring 2.0.x and this has something to do in failure. Second thoughts are on tomcat, but then I have already added this dependency:

```
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
```

EDIT:
Posting my build.gradle

```
    dependencies {
    compileOnly(
            "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.+",
    )
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compile(
            "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter",
            "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-reactive",
            "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas",
            //"org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-eureka",
            "io.projectreactor:reactor-core:3.2.2.RELEASE",
    )
    compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-all', version: '0.3.0.RELEASE'
    //compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-feign:', version:'1.4.0.RELEASE'
        compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth')
    compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '23.0'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-commons', version: '2.0.2.RELEASE'
    testCompile group: 'ru.yandex.qatools.allure', name: 'allure-junit-adaptor', version: '1.5.4'


    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude group : "junit" , module : "junit"
    }

    testCompile(
            "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-test-support",
            "org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:1.5.+",

            'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api',
    )
    testRuntimeOnly(
            'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine',
    )
    testRuntime(
            'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher',
            'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-runner',
    )

    testCompileOnly (
            "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.+",
    )

}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.0.3.RELEASE"
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Finchley.RELEASE"
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud.stream.app:app-starters-core-dependencies:2.0.1.RELEASE"
        mavenBom "org.junit:junit-bom:5.3.1"
    }
}
configurations.all {
    exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-simple'
    exclude group: "com.sun.jdmk", module: 'jmxtools'
    exclude group: "com.sun.jmx", module: 'jmxri'
}
```

Comment: Add the full logging output. Currently there is too little information.

Comment: Post your full POM

Comment: added my dependencies block

Comment: You may not have downloaded the new dependencies correctly or may be running a cached version of your application start by running
`./gradlew clean build`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the issue of Spring Actuator HealthPoint.
The previous healthpoint was :/manage/health

In Spring 2.0.x, this is changed to /actuator/health

And my Kubernetes liveliness probe was trying to hit the URL. 3 unsuccessful attempts to hit /manage/health led to the POD going down.

Changed the whitelisting from to /actuator/health and it worked